# AngularJS assign function to scope member doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I followed a tutorial to learn it. When I tried to assign a string literal to scope member it works, but it doesn't work if assigned a function instead. The code is as follow:

[image]

The result becomes the member value is assigned the definition text of the function, instead of the return value of the function. Any idea? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`tutorialName`** is a function, so you should use the function *()* inside the expression

```
<br> This tutorial is {{tutorialName()}} </br>
```